# How can I optimize this nested grouping?

Tags: xslt-1.0, muenchian-grouping

I have an XML as below example, that can contain up to 5000 lines, but I've limited it to 20 to be a bit reasonable.

```
<PMT NM="rnt-model">
<PV V="L11-L23-L3448-L42375_MODEL1" C="1"></PV>
<PV V="L11-L23-L3448-L448_MODEL2" C="1"></PV>
<PV V="L11-L23-L3448-L448_MODEL3" C="1"></PV>
<PV V="L11-L23-L3448-L448_MODEL4" C="1"></PV>
<PV V="L11-L23-L3448-L448_MODEL5" C="2"></PV>
<PV V="L11-L24-L319-L493_MODEL6" C="1"></PV>
<PV V="L11-L25-L3288-L41931_MODEL7" C="1"></PV>
<PV V="L110-L254-L3217-L41303_MODEL8" C="1"></PV>
<PV V="L110-L254-L3217-L41303_MODEL9" C="1"></PV>
<PV V="L110-L254-L3217-L41303_MODEL10" C="1"></PV>
<PV V="L110-L254-L3217-L41303_MODEL11" C="1"></PV>
<PV V="L110-L254-L3217-L41303_MODEL12" C="1"></PV>
<PV V="L110-L254-L3217-L41303_MODEL13" C="1"></PV>
<PV V="L110-L254-L3217-L41303_MODEL14" C="1"></PV>
<PV V="L110-L254-L3217-L41303_MODEL15" C="1"></PV>
<PV V="L110-L254-L3217-L41303_MODEL16" C="1"></PV>
<PV V="L110-L254-L3217-L41303_MODEL17" C="1"></PV>
<PV V="L110-L254-L3217-L41303_MODEL18" C="1"></PV>
<PV V="L110-L254-L3218-L41307_MODEL19" C="1"></PV>
<PV V="L110-L254-L3218-L41307_MODEL20" C="1"></PV>
</PMT>
```

The XML has to be transformed from this pseudo flat format to a tree structure based on @V. @V needs to be split in 2 first based on the underscore, and then tokenized on the hyphen.

Or to make it more visible, below is the expected outcome.

```
<root>
<n id="L11">
    <n id="L23">
        <n id="L3448">
            <n id="L42375">
                <n m="MODEL1" c="1"></n>
            </n>
            <n id="L448">
                <n m="MODEL2" c="1"></n>
                <n m="MODEL3" c="1"></n>
                <n m="MODEL4" c="1"></n>
                <n m="MODEL5" c="2"></n>
            </n>
        </n>
    </n>
    <!-- rest of rows below -->
```

I managed to get it working using below XSLT, and it works pretty ok when the amount of rows is small. However, when using real live XML it takes a lot of time to generate the tree so I'm wondering how I can make things more efficient. It's pretty straightforward to do in XSLT2, but I'm stuck with 1.0 for the project I'm working on.

XSLT code used (working but not very efficient)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="level1" use="@L1" match="row"/>
<xsl:key name="level2" use="@L2" match="row"/>
<xsl:key name="level3" use="@L3" match="row"/>
<xsl:key name="level4" use="@L4" match="row"/>
<xsl:template match="//PMT[@NM='rnt-model']">
    <root>
        <!-- Step 1 : generate a table with all the tokenized attributes -->
        <xsl:variable name="theTree">
            <xsl:for-each select="PV">
                <row>
                    <xsl:for-each select="@V">
                        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize_tree">
                            <xsl:with-param name="list" select="substring-before(.,'_')"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="'-'"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                        <xsl:attribute name="M"><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'_')"/></xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:attribute name="C"><xsl:value-of select="@C"/></xsl:attribute>
                </row>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- Step 2 : Group all -->

        <xsl:for-each select="$theTree//row[generate-id()=generate-id(key('level1',@L1)[1])]">
            <xsl:variable name="theType" select="@L1"/>
            <n id="{$theType}">
                <xsl:for-each select="$theTree/row[@L1=$theType][generate-id()=generate-id(key('level2',@L2)[1])]">
                    <xsl:variable name="theCat" select="@L2"/>
                    <n id="{$theCat}">
                        <xsl:for-each select="$theTree/row[@L2=$theCat][generate-id()=generate-id(key('level3',@L3)[1])]">
                            <xsl:variable name="theSubCat" select="@L3"/>
                            <n id="{$theSubCat}">
                                <xsl:for-each select="$theTree/row[@L3=$theSubCat][generate-id()=generate-id(key('level4',@L4)[1])]">
                                    <xsl:variable name="theSerie" select="@L4"/>
                                    <n id="{$theSerie}">
                                        <xsl:for-each select="$theTree/row[@L4=$theSerie]">
                                            <n m="{@M}" c="{@C}"/>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </n>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </n>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </n>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </n>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="tokenize_tree">
    <!--passed template parameter -->
    <xsl:param name="list"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($list, $delimiter)">
            <xsl:attribute name="{substring(substring-before($list,$delimiter),1,2)}"><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($list,$delimiter)"/></xsl:attribute>
            <!-- get everything in front of the first delimiter -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize_tree">
                <!-- store anything left in another variable -->
                <xsl:with-param name="list" select="substring-after($list,$delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$list = ''">
                    <xsl:text/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:attribute name="{substring($list,1,2)}"><xsl:value-of select="$list"/></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any ideas on how to improve efficiency so it works faster with bigger files ?

Answer (score 1):

Efficiency is very much processor-dependent, but perhaps you should try a single-pass approach:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="level1" match="PV" use="substring-before(@V, '-')" />
<xsl:key name="level2" match="PV" use="substring-before(substring-after(@V, '-'),  '-')" />
<xsl:key name="level3" match="PV" use="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(@V, '-'),  '-'),  '-')" />
<xsl:key name="level4" match="PV" use="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(@V, '-'),  '-'),  '-'), '_')" />

<xsl:template match="/PMT">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="PV[count(. | key('level1', substring-before(@V, '-'))[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:variable name="L1" select="substring-before(@V, '-')" />           
            <n id="{$L1}">
                <xsl:for-each select="key('level1', $L1)[count(. | key('level2', substring-before(substring-after(@V, '-'), '-'))[1]) = 1]">
                <xsl:variable name="L2" select="substring-before(substring-after(@V, '-'), '-')" />         
                    <n id="{$L2}">
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('level2', $L2)[count(. | key('level3', substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(@V, '-'),  '-'),  '-'))[1]) = 1]">
                        <xsl:variable name="L3" select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(@V, '-'),  '-'),  '-')" />         
                            <n id="{$L3}">
                                <xsl:for-each select="key('level3', $L3)[count(. | key('level4', substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(@V, '-'),  '-'),  '-'), '_'))[1]) = 1]">
                                <xsl:variable name="L4" select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(@V, '-'),  '-'),  '-'), '_')" />           
                                    <n id="{$L4}">
                                        <xsl:for-each select="key('level4', $L4)">
                                            <n m="{substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(@V, '-'),  '-'),  '-'), '_')}" c="{@C}"/>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </n>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </n>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </n>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </n>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note also that an explicit path will usually be more efficient than `//`.

Comment: Thanks, it's a bit faster indeed but not the hoped speedbump as such. Frankly speaking I'm not sure if there is a huge improvement possible, so the effort is for sure appreciated !